Why does leaflet fit bounds do this?
When I use map.fitbounds to center a map it messes up everything the problem is attached below. When it should look like formated and all. Could anyone please help thank you?? The problem, if the images don't work is that the sidebar is missing and the header is moved to the side. It has been tested problem comes from the fitbounds rule.
The code for the leaflet verison is
 var map = L.map('map-canvas').setView([<%= correctAns.location.lat %>, <%= correctAns.location.longg %>], 3);
// Add the tile layer
// Initialize the map with the original center and zoom level
var map = L.map('map-canvas', {
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 6
}).setView([<%= correctAns.location.lat %>, <%= correctAns.location.longg %>], 6);
// Add the tile layer
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
@@ -169,53 +176,70 @@ bounds.extend(correctMarker.getLatLng());
// Function to create colored icon (unchanged)
function createColoredIcon(color) {
  const svgTemplate = `
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="marker">
      <path fill-opacity=".25" d="M16 32s1.427-9.585 3.761-12.025c4.595-4.805 8.685-.99 8.685-.99s4.044 3.964-.526 8.743C25.514 30.245 16 32 16 32z"/>
      <path fill="#${color}" stroke="#fff" d="M15.938 32S6 17.938 6 11.938C6 .125 15.938 0 15.938 0S26 .125 26 11.875C26 18.062 15.938 32 15.938 32zM16 6a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8z"/>
    </svg>`;
  return L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svgTemplate),
    iconSize: [32, 32],
    iconAnchor: [16, 32],
    popupAnchor: [0, -32]
  });
    const svgTemplate = `
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="marker">
            <path fill-opacity=".25" d="M16 32s1.427-9.585 3.761-12.025c4.595-4.805 8.685-.99 8.685-.99s4.044 3.964-.526 8.743C25.514 30.245 16 32 16 32z"/>
            <path fill="#${color}" stroke="#fff" d="M15.938 32S6 17.938 6 11.938C6 .125 15.938 0 15.938 0S26 .125 26 11.875C26 18.062 15.938 32 15.938 32zM16 6a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8z"/>
        </svg>`;
    return L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svgTemplate),
        iconSize: [32, 32],
        iconAnchor: [16, 32],
        popupAnchor: [0, -32]
    });
}
// Add user answer markers and extend bounds
<% allUsers.forEach(function(user) { %>
  <% if (user.answer && user.answer.loc) { %>
    var userColor = '<%= user.color %>'.replace('#', ''); // Remove '#' if present
    var userIcon = createColoredIcon(userColor);
    var userMarker = L.marker([<%= user.answer.loc.lat %>, <%= user.answer.loc.longg %>], {
      icon: userIcon
    }).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("<%= user.name %>'s Answer");
    
    bounds.extend(userMarker.getLatLng());
  <% } %>
    <% if (user.answer && user.answer.loc) { %>
        var userColor = '<%= user.color %>'.replace('#', '');
        var userIcon = createColoredIcon(userColor);
        var userMarker = L.marker([<%= user.answer.loc.lat %>, <%= user.answer.loc.longg %>], {
            icon: userIcon
        }).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<%= user.name %>'s Answer");
        
        bounds.extend(userMarker.getLatLng());
    <% } %>
<% }); %>
// Adjust the view to fit all markers
// Function to check if all markers are visible
function areAllMarkersVisible() {
    var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
    return bounds.toBBoxString() === mapBounds.toBBoxString() || bounds.within(mapBounds);
}
// Function to find appropriate zoom level
function findAppropriateZoom() {
    var currentZoom = 6; // Start at max zoom
    map.setView(bounds.getCenter(), currentZoom);
    
    while (currentZoom > 2 && !areAllMarkersVisible()) {
        currentZoom--;
        map.setZoom(currentZoom);
    }
    
    return currentZoom;
}
// Adjust the view to fit all markers with adaptive zoom
map.fitBounds(bounds, {
    padding: [50, 50], // Add 50 pixels of padding
    maxZoom: 15, // Limit the max zoom level
    animate: false // Disable animation for instant change
    padding: [50, 50],
    maxZoom: 6,
    minZoom: 2,
    animate: false
});
 <% allUsers.forEach(function(user) { %>
  <% if (user.answer && user.answer.loc) { %>
    var userColor = '<%= user.color %>'.replace('#', ''); // Remove '#' if present
    var userIcon = createColoredIcon(userColor);
// Find and set appropriate zoom level
var appropriateZoom = findAppropriateZoom();
map.setView(bounds.getCenter(), appropriateZoom, { animate: false });
    var marker2 = L.marker([<%= user.answer.loc.lat %>, <%= user.answer.loc.longg %>], {
      icon: userIcon
    }).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("<%= user.name %>'s Answer");
  <% } %>
<% }); %>
// Ensure we're not too zoomed out
if (map.getZoom() < 2) {
    map.setZoom(2);
}
 
        window.onload = function(){
            <% if (auto!='yes'){ %>
@@ -239,4 +263,4 @@ map.fitBounds(bounds, {


</body>
</html>
</html>


Please try to keep question titles as self-explanatory and concise as possible and clarify what you mean by "this". Probably an alignment or scaling problem. Also, please try to add a running snippet to illustrate the issue. Try to reduce the code to the bare minimum to reproduce this problem. Your current code seems to deploy some template library/framework you haven't mentioned.
